# Use of Popups in Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I have the error below when I try to show an alert popup after click on a button:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in
>   [null] ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined

This is my code:

popups.html:

```
<ion-content padding class="getting-started">

   <button primary (click)="showAlertPopup()">Alert</button>

</ion-content>
```

popups.js

```
import {Page, NavController, Popup} from 'ionic/ionic';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'app/popups/popups.html'
})

export class PopupsPage {
  constructor(nav: NavController, popup: Popup) {
       this.nav = nav;
       this.popup = popup;
  }

  showAlertPopup(){
       this.popup.alert({
           title: 'Ionic Popup',
           template: 'This is alert popup'
       });
  }
}
```

Some tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a bug with the Ionic2 version. Working as expected after update to version alpha 37.

Answer (score 1):

For those visiting this question in >=2017, you should use the [AlertController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/).

An example:

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

presentAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Low battery',
        subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
        buttons: ['Dismiss']
     });
     alert.present();
}
```

See the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) for more examples like ConfirmAlert, PromptAlert, etc.